# Heat resistant odor neutralizers

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I am looking for a heat-resistant odor neutralizer that can be released into the air at 200 degrees Fahrenheit and still be effective.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If it is just for household and pet odors, why does it need to be effective at 200 degrees Fahrenheit?

Answer (score 1):

Metazene 99% or other Alpha Aromatics high heat compounds.

What is the mal-odor caused by, and the complete application?

Comment: Pet odor / household odors. Application is for candle wax.

Comment: This isn't really an answer to the question.  Can you explain what metazene is (it's not a standard chemical term), what "alpha aromatics high heat compounds" are, and add more details?  If you have comments or clarifications to ask the OP, those can be done in comments, not in your submitted answer.  Thanks for participating in chem.SE, glad to have you here.

Answer (score 1):

Ozone is widely used commercially and residentially for the destruction of odor causing gases and particulates (i.e. smoke), and a variety of different types of ozone generators are readily available.  According to [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone#Production):

> Ozone generators are used to produce ozone for cleaning air or
>   removing smoke odours[69] in unoccupied rooms. These ozone generators
>   can produce over 3 g of ozone per hour.

This is a reference to an extremely high-capacity device. The rest of the above article further describes the array of ozone generators that are commercially available.

Of course, ozone truly destroys malodorous compounds as opposed to covering them up. The rate of destruction of these compounds also generally increases with increasing temperature.